# Handling errors on a web application

Tags: c#, error-handling, email

I have this C# production code for handling errors on a web application. There are currently two applications that use the class. In each application I initialize the class within the `Page_Init` method in a base class that is used on every page. Some methods are used to actually display the message whereas other methods will just email the message.

I wonder if maybe I should refactor it into two separate classes and/or use an interface to improve its scalability. Any thoughts?

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;

/// <summary>
/// Handles displaying messages and sending notifications
/// </summary>
public class ExceptionHandler
{
    private SessionManager session;
    private EmailProvider email;
    private EnvironmentProvider environmentProvider;
    private AppLocations appLocation;

    public ExceptionHandler(SessionManager userSession = null)
    {
        environmentProvider = new EnvironmentProvider();
        appLocation         = environmentProvider.GetLocation();
        session             = userSession;
        email               = new EmailProvider(session);
    }

    public void ShowMessage(Exception ex, HtmlGenericControl errorPanel, HttpRequest request, HttpServerUtility server, string messageKey = "")
    {
        SetMessage(errorPanel, server, messageKey);
        if (ex.IsNotNull())
        {
            email.SendExceptionDetails(GetEmailDetails(ex, request));
        }
    }

    public void ShowSessionMessage(HtmlGenericControl errorPanel, HttpRequest request, HttpServerUtility server, MessageKeyGroup sessionMessageKeys)
    {
        bool isGeneric = false;
        string message = sessionMessageKeys.MessageKey;
        if (message.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            message   = GetHtmlDecodedMessage(server, "GenericErrorMessage");
            isGeneric = true;
        }

        string loginUrl = GetLoginURL();
        if (loginUrl.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            email.SendExceptionDetails(GetEmailDetails(new NullReferenceException("Login URL is null."), request));
            message = GetHtmlDecodedMessage(server, isGeneric ? "GenericErrorMessageWithoutButton" : sessionMessageKeys.AlternateMessageKey);
            errorPanel.InnerHtml = GetHtmlDecodedMessage(server, message);
            errorPanel.Visible   = true;
            return;
        }
        errorPanel.InnerHtml = String.Format(GetHtmlDecodedMessage(server, message), loginUrl);
        errorPanel.Visible   = true;
    }

    public void ShowExistingClaimMessage(HtmlGenericControl errorPanel, HttpRequest request, HttpServerUtility server, string messageKey)
    {
        errorPanel.InnerHtml = GetHtmlDecodedMessage(server, messageKey);
        errorPanel.Visible = true;
    }

    public void SendExceptionInfo(Exception ex, HttpRequest request)
    {
        if (ex is DbEntityValidationException)
        {
            DbEntityValidationException dbEx = (DbEntityValidationException)ex;
            email.SendExceptionDetails(GetEFValidationExceptionDetails(dbEx, request));
            return;
        }
        email.SendExceptionDetails(GetEmailDetails(ex, request));
    }

    public void SendExceptionInfo(Exception ex)
    {
        email.SendException(ex);
    }

    private ExceptionEmailDetails GetEmailDetails(Exception ex, HttpRequest request)
    {
        string serverName = request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
        string serverHost = request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"];
        return new ExceptionEmailDetails()
        {
            SystemException = ex,
            ServerName = serverName,
            ServerHost = serverHost
        };
    }

    private ExceptionEmailDetails GetEFValidationExceptionDetails(DbEntityValidationException ex, HttpRequest request)
    {
        string msg = string.Empty;
        foreach (var validationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
            {
                msg += String.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1} {2}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage, Environment.NewLine);
                //Debug.WriteLine(msg);
                //Trace.TraceInformation(msg);
            }
        }
        ExceptionEmailDetails details = GetEmailDetails(ex, request);
        details.BodyPrefix = msg;
        return details;
    }

    private void SetMessage(HtmlGenericControl errorPanel, HttpServerUtility server, string companyName, string messageKey = "")
    {
        string message = GetHtmlDecodedMessage(server, "ClaimErrorMessage");
        if (messageKey.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
        {
            message = GetHtmlDecodedMessage(server, messageKey);
        }
        if (companyName.IsNull())
        {
            message = GetHtmlDecodedMessage(server, "GenericPolicyErrorMessage");
        }
        errorPanel.InnerHtml = companyName.IsNull() ? message : String.Format(message, companyName);
        errorPanel.Visible = true;
    }

    public string GetHtmlDecodedMessage(HttpServerUtility server, string messageKey)
    {
        return server.HtmlDecode(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[messageKey]);
    }

    private string GetLoginURL()
    {
        switch (appLocation)
        {
            case AppLocations.Development:
                return WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoginURLforDev"];
            case AppLocations.Staging:
                return WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoginURLforStaging"];
            case AppLocations.Production:
                return WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoginURLforProd"];
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public void SendErrorMessage(string subject, string body)
    {
        email.SendMessage(body, subject, null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use Elmah or NLog from Nuget. It stored to DB , sneds emails and Elmah streamlines nicely in MVC.. and even WebForms.

Comment: I know about ELMAH and plan to integrate it into our architecture at some point in the future, but that wont happen anytime soon. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your class has implicit dependencies which should be passed in because otherwise unit testing can become painful. Those are `EnvironmentProvider` and `EmailProvider`.

   Now while looking at these it becomes obvious that `EnvironmentProvider` is purely used to retrieve the `appLocation` and it should therefore be removed as class member.

   Checking further it seems that `appLocation` is purely used to obtain a `loginUrl`. Hence the class can be simplified by just passing the login URL via the constructor and let something else worry about to obtain it. This removes a concern from the class which it really shouldn't have to deal with. You could even make that a parameter to `ShowSessionMessage` which is the only method which cares about it and remove that dependency from the class all together.
2. This code seems slightly weird:

   ```
   message = GetHtmlDecodedMessage(server, isGeneric ? "GenericErrorMessageWithoutButton" : sessionMessageKeys.AlternateMessageKey);
   errorPanel.InnerHtml = GetHtmlDecodedMessage(server, message);
   ```

   Looks like it decodes the message twice. It might not matter or might even be required but still looks strange.

Comment: Thanks Chris, your comments were very helpful as they forced me to look at some possible issues. Your suggestions for improvement sound logical.